# Keep data in javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to populate an array with javascript everytime I hit a button.

Eg.: if array is `{[10,2,5]}` and I hit the button again it should be `{[10,2,5],[6,3,4]}`

Q: This could be done? Could you give me a start point?

```
$('#button').click(function()     {
//populating array keeping old data everytime user push button.
}

<form id="myForm">
    //data that ill go to array
    <input type="button" id="button" value="ok">
</form>
```

Comment: What happens if the user refreshes the page?

Comment: You mean `[[10,2,5],[6,3,4]]` :)

Comment: those values are just examples

Comment: Can't help with the button click handler without knowing where the new data comes from.

Comment: ok ill update the code a bit more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myArray = [];

$('#button').click(function(){
  var newArray = [];
  myArray.push(newArray);
});
```

Comment: This solved parte of my question :) Ill open new question to solve another thing now